# how often to update deposit address of the blockchain.info API

Tags: blockchain.info, payment

how often should I update the users deposit address if I'm using the blockchain receive payments API V2?

Comment: Perhaps if you gave more information about what you're trying to achieve, someone could answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

So I did some research and it seems addresses with the blockchain.info API are only useful for a week. so update once a week if no payments are coming in incase of a payment that's the other que to update your address.